# In JMeter, Is there a way to run a set of two rest api's(which have to run one after another) 10 times in parallel

Tags: api, rest, jmeter

In JMeter, I have two samplers(both REST api calls) in a thread group which run sequentially. Is there a way to run this set of two api's 10 times in parallel.

I have two rest api calls, 1st one POST which gives a "Id" and then a GET call which uses this Id as a path parameter. These two api calls have to run sequentially. - This I have achieved.
Now what I want to do is run this set of two apis(which have to run one after the other) 10 times in parallel. Is there a way in JMeter?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H3Ud.png)

Comment: Your sequential set of two api are running perfectly. Just increase the threads to 10 and ramup set as empty. Or else you can also try using [parallel controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

Each JMeter thread (virtual user) executes [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))

If you want to execute this sequence of 2 request 10 times - just [add more Threads](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users) (virtual users) on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level

[image]

you can also specify there virtual users arrival rate (so called [ramp-up period](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide/)) so users will arrive either at the same time or the load will increase gradually, number of loops (iterations) for each virtual user and the desired duration of the test

You may also be interested in [Custom Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups) which provide possibility to create advanced workload patterns quickly and easily, moreover you will be able to see anticipated number of virtual users in interactive chart:

[image]